# React how to trigger a specific scroll event(arrowUp or arrowDown inside a div) on a key press

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I developed chat web application.
I wish to fire scroll event on a specific div(chatPage) whenever (for example)"w" or "s" keys is pressed,
exactly the same way if the chatPage div had the focus on, and ArrowUp or ArrowDown keys was pressed.

Notice: I wish to mimic the default scroll event fired on the browser when "ArrowUp" or "ArrowDown" keys is pressed when a div element have the focus and not accomplish it by other method such as calling current.scrollBy on the reference of the div.

(not like this) :

```
this.state.chatPageRef.current.scrollBy(0, -20);  //"w" key has preesed
this.state.chatPageRef.current.scrollBy(0, 20);   //"s" key has preesed
```

This works ok, but not smoothly as the default scroll of the browser when the arrows keys is being pressed.
Also, I do not wish to use any external React API that knows how to trigger events but using only React standard libraries.

instead, i wish to use more something like this:

```
var scrollEvent = new Event("scroll", {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
      view: window
      // probobaly here some proparties need to be added 
    });
document.getElementById("chatPage").dispatchEvent(scrollEvent)
```

Which does fire a scroll event, but not the same event as explained above so its do nothing.

I do not know how to define the Event() constructor to mimic the
exact event fired by the browser whenever  "ArrowUp" or "ArrowDown" keys is pressed when a specific div element have the focus on.

So my question is, how can I find out how to exactly define my scroll Event constructor to mimic specific default browser event(such as scroll a div via arrows on keyboard)?
(answers with instructions how to find out the properties of this specific event via console.log() would also be blessed)

thanks...!

Answer (score 0):

The security model in the browser, blocks direct access to a number of events like this. The solution will be to manually animate the scrolling using `requestAnimationFrame` to feed smaller increments to the code in your question.

Comment: If APIs for firing such events exist, there must be solution for this without APIs. (fireEvent can do this, but I don't want to use any external APIs especially not one that is supposed to be used only in development)